# Sender e-mail adress when two accounts are set up in Outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007

I have two e-mail accounts in my Outlook and when replying e-mails, I don't want to choose all the the time the account which will be sent with. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

For Outlook 2007

```
Select Tools | Account Settings... from the menu.
Highlight the desired account.
Click Set as Default.
Now click Close.
```

REF: http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/How_to_Set_the_Default_Account_in_Outlook.htm